# Обработка ошибки в программе

Tags: c#, .net

Недавно я решил одну небольшую задачу и сейчас хочу ее модифицировать. Вот собственно задача:

У нас есть входные данные:

```
push Привет! Это снова я! Пока!
pop 5
push Как твои успехи? Плохо?
push qwertyuiop
push 1234567890
pop 26
```

Вообщем, в чем суть: у нас есть массив строк в котором записаны команды. В начале каждой команды есть одно из двух ключевых слов `push` или `pop`. После слова `push` пишется текст, после слова `pop` обязательно число. У нас есть переменная `text` и если команда начинается с ключевого слова `push` то эта команда добавляется в данную переменную и, логично, ключевое слово удаляется. Если же команда начинается с `pop`,то после этого слова должна идти цифра, эта цифра означает количество символов которые нужно удалить в предыдущей строке которая начиналась `push`. Вот пример:

Допустим у нас есть команда `push Hello, World!`

Что должна вывести программа:

```
Hello, World!
```

Затем идет следующая команда `pop 3`

Что выводит программа:

```
Hello, Wor
```

Ну так вот, когда я только написал эту программу, я тестил ее на уже известных мне входных данных, сейчас же я решил сделать так чтобы пользователь сам вводил команды. И понятное дело при такой системе может возникнуть немало ошибок так как пользователь может ввести все что угодно. Поэтому в данный момент я занимаюсь обработкой потенциальных ошибок. Сейчас я хочу обработать исключение при котором пользователь будет вводить только ключевые слова `push/pop` и ничего больше. Я хочу чтобы при данном вводе программа выдавала не исключение, а например сообщение в котором будет указана ошибка.

Вот мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace PushPopLibrary
{

 public class PushPop
 {
    public static string ApplyCommands(string[] commands)
    {
        var text = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            if (command.StartsWith("push"))
            {
                var pushRemove = command.Remove(0, 5).TrimStart(' '); //здесь я так-же удаляю пробел в начале строки
                text.Append(pushRemove);
            }
            else if (command.StartsWith("pop"))
            {
                var commandSplit = command.Split();
                var count = commandSplit[1];
                if (text.Length < int.Parse(count))
                {
                    return "Длина текста меньше указанного числа";
                }
                else
                {
                    text.Length -= int.Parse(count);
                }
            }
            else if (text.Length == 0)
            {
                return "Вы не написали текст!";
            }
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Этот код написан в библиотечном проекте. Вот основной файл:

```
using PushPopLibrary;

namespace MyFirstApp
{

  class Program
  {
     public static void Main()
     {
        string[] commands = new string[] { Console.ReadLine() };
        Console.WriteLine(PushPop.ApplyCommands(commands));
     }
   }
```

И еще вопрос: как мне сделать эту программу цикличной? Проблема в том что когда я ввожу строку к примеру `push Hello` программа делает все правильно, а именно возвращает мне эту строку удаляя при этом ключевое слово в начале, но на этом программа останавливается, соответственно у меня не получается написать следующую команду только уже с ключевым словом `pop` чтобы удалить определенное кол-во символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      List<string> commands = new List<string>();

      var userInput = "";

      while ( true ) {
         userInput = Console.ReadLine();

         if (userInput == "exit")
             break;

         if (userInput.StartsWith("pop") || userInput.StartsWith("push")) {
             commands.append(userInput);
             Console.WriteLine(PushPop.ApplyCommands(commands));
         }
         else {
             Console.WriteLine("Строка должна начинатся с push или pop; Или же введите команду Exit для выхода");
         }
      
      }
   }
 }
```

все что ты хотел.

Могут быть мелкие синтаксические или логические ошибки т.к. писал без вижуалки и с другой операционки.

Answer (score 4):

То что вы научились использовать классы и отдельные сборки для того, чтобы разделить структуру и задачи своего приложения - хорошо. Но почему-то вы не пользуетесь этими навыками для организации структур данных, и передаете данные от метода к методу в сыром виде.

Если у вас есть конкретная задача, то и данные можно организовать конкретным образом.

Например так:

```cs
public enum InputCommandType
{
    Unknown,
    Push,
    Pop
}

public interface IInputCommand
{
    public InputCommandType Type { get; }
}

public class InputCommand<T> : IInputCommand
{
    public InputCommandType Type { get; }

    public T Value { get; }

    public InputCommand(InputCommandType type, T value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Type = {Type}, Value = {Value}";
    }
}
```

Здесь все просто: интерфейс нужен, чтобы разные типы команд можно было класть в один и тот же список, а значение хранит уже то что вам нужно в готовом формате.

То есть эта модель данных позволит сохранить данные в формате, готовом для обработки. Парсим отдельно, обрабатываем отдельно. Еще одно разделение - хорошо, потому что добавит больше гибкости в будущей разработке, вы же не собираетесь останавливаться на двух командах?

Метод считывания этого всего с консоли может выглядеть так:

```cs
static List<IInputCommand> ReadInputCommands()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите пустую строку или \"exit\", чтобы остановить ввод.");
    List<IInputCommand> input = new List<IInputCommand>();
    while (true)
    {
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line.Length == 0 || line.ToLower() == "exit")
            break;
        try
        {
            input.Add(ParseCommand(line));
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Ввод завершен, спасибо.");
    return input;
}

static IInputCommand ParseCommand(string input)
{
    string[] tokens = input.Split(' ', 2);
    if (tokens.Length < 2)
        throw new FormatException("Введенная строка имеет неверный формат.");
    Enum.TryParse(tokens[0], true, out InputCommandType commandType);
    switch (commandType)
    {
        case InputCommandType.Push:
            if (tokens[1].Length > 0)
                return new InputCommand<string>(commandType, tokens[1]);
            else
                throw new FormatException("Команда push поддерживает только не пустую строку в качестве параметра.");
        case InputCommandType.Pop:
            if (int.TryParse(tokens[1], out int value) && value > 0)
                return new InputCommand<int>(commandType, value);
            else
                throw new FormatException("Команда pop поддерживает только положительное число в качестве параметра.");
        default:
            throw new FormatException("Непонятная команда, попробуйте еще раз.");
    }
}
```

Так как данные уже в готовом виде, обработать их теперь просто. Вот ваш переписанный метод обработки:

```cs
static string ApplyCommands(IEnumerable<IInputCommand> commands)
{
    var text = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var command in commands)
    {
        switch (command.Type)
        {
            case InputCommandType.Push when command is InputCommand<string> pushCommand:
                text.Append(pushCommand.Value);
                break;
            case InputCommandType.Pop when command is InputCommand<int> popCommand:
                if (popCommand.Value > text.Length)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Длина текста меньше указанного числа: {popCommand}");
                else
                    text.Length -= popCommand.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Использовать это предельно просто

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<IInputCommand> input = ReadInputCommands();
    string text = ApplyCommands(input);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите пустую строку или "exit", чтобы остановить ввод.
push Hello W
push orld
pop 5
push artgor
push !!!

Ввод завершен, спасибо.
Hello artgor!!!
```

Ну и обработку ошибок ввода вы сами можете протестировать.